# How can I group MySQL Workbench connections?

Tags: mysql-workbench

During several years of activity, I accumulated dozens of Database Connections in MySQL Workbench. So many that finding the right one is becoming more and more a challenge. Is there a way to group connections, tidying up the home screen ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, just right click on connection and choose `Move to Group...`, then you can create new group or select an existing one.

Comment: Easy enough... the shorter, the better ! I like your answer better than mine !

Comment: After creating a group, you can use drag-and-drop to move connections to it (MacOS v. 8.0.29).

Answer (score 0):

It's incredible I could not find this on StackOverflow, but googling for a while I arrived to this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-home.html

Under **MySQL Connections** we read

> **Connection Groups**.  You may also create groups of connections. Create a group by either right-clicking a connection and choosing the Move to group context menu option, or you may prefix your connection name with the group name separated by a forward slash (for example, "QA/TestBox") when you create or configure the connection.

So basically changing the connection name from

```
MySystem Connection - Production
```

to

```
MySystem Connection/Production
```

it created a Group Folder in the home screen.